# Word placement in character vector in R for specific condition

Tags: xml, r

I couldn't get the heading right. Sorry for that! 
I have the xml file input as follows and it is a character vector:

```
[1]<step>
[2]<caution-ref>
[3]<h5><hdtitle>Caution</hdtitle></h5>
[4]Refer to
[5]<object-link object-id="183615"></object-link> in Cautions and
[6]Notices.
[7]</caution-ref>
```

I want to remove `[1]<step>` before `[2]<caution-ref>` and place it after `[7]</caution-ref>`.

Important: All the files do not contain `<caution-ref>`at [2] and `</caution-ref>` at [7]. The next `</caution-ref>` could occur anywhere. i.e. [4]/[5]/[n] etc

So, the output is as follows

```
[1]<caution-ref>
[2]<h5><hdtitle>Caution</hdtitle></h5>
[3]Refer to
[4]<object-link object-id="183615"></object-link> in Cautions and
[5]Notices.
[6]</caution-ref><step>
```

Here is my code, it doesn't work for every case

```
#x1 is the input file
#I have added conditions for exceptions handling
x1 <- readLines("test.xml")
x2 <- x1
x3 <- character(length(x2))

for ( i in 1:length(x1)){ 
  if (grepl("<step",x1[i])==TRUE & grepl("<caution-ref",x1[i+1])==TRUE & grepl("</step",x1[i])==F & grepl("</step",x1[i+1])==F)
  {
    x2[i]<- gsub("<step>","",x1[i])

    x3 <- x2
    for ( a in 1:length(x2)){ 
      if (grepl("</caution-ref>",x2[a])==TRUE & grepl("</step>",x2[a+1])==F & grepl("</step>",x2[a])==F & grepl("<step>",x2[a])==F & grepl("<step>",x2[a+1])==F)
      {
        x3[a]<- gsub("</caution-ref>","</caution-ref><step>",x2[a])
        x2[a] <- x3[a]
      }}}
  else{
    x3[i] <- x2[i]
  }
}

x3 <- x3[!is.na(x3)]
x3 <- x3[sapply(x3, nchar) > 0]
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe you should consider to use a package for handling xml data, like `XML` or maybe `R2HTML`.

Comment: @drmariod that's not a valid XML file so Karan can't use `XML::xmlParse`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very crude way that makes many assumptions, but it works well for your example:

```
x2 <- x1

stepIdx <- grep("<step>", x1)
endIdx <- grep("</caution-ref>", x1)

x2[endIdx] <- "</caution-ref><step>"
x2 <- x2[-stepIdx]
```

It assumes `<step>` and `</caution-ref>` are always a line on its own, and doesn't check for cases where the structure is not `<step>` then an enclosure of `<caution-ref>` ... `</caution-ref>` etc. I.e. no exception handling.

If that's all you want, see the result below.

```
> x2
[1] "<caution-ref>"                                                   
[2] "<h5><hdtitle>Caution</hdtitle></h5>"                             
[3] "Refer to"                                                        
[4] "<object-link object-id=\"183615\"></object-link> in Cautions and"
[5] "Notices."                                                        
[6] "</caution-ref><step>"
```